# Como Realizar Un backUp Automatico en MySQL

Tags: mysql, batch

Este Script lo he adelantado pero no se por que no me funciona no ubico el error si alguien me puede Ayudar?

```
@echo off
mysqldump -h localhost  -u root  -p Dotado256   sixstar_almacen  >  AlmacenBeta _ 19082018.sql
Pause
```

Uso Xammp la base Datos es (sixstar_almacen) Obvio sin entre parentesis,
yo lo que quiero que al hacer Click este Bat me haga el .SQL en mi PC pero no me sale

Comment: que bases/tablas queres hacer backup?

Comment: Respondido y editado mi consulta amigo agradezco ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En notación corta: (revisar bien los espacios)

```
@echo off
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pDotado256 sixstar_almacen > AlmacenBeta_19082018.sql
Pause
```

Notación Extendida (`--result-file` es para que windows no te grabe el archivo en UTF-16 o reemplace los `\n` con `\r\n`)

```
@echo off
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root -password=Dotado256 --databases sixstar_almacen --result-file=AlmacenBeta_19082018.sql
Pause
```

Tal vez tengas que cambiar `localhost` por `127.0.0.1` si los permisos del usuario están por ip y no por comodín.

Si el archivo de salida incluye espacios ponerlo entre comillas dobles:

```
"AlmacenBeta 19082018.sql"
```

Por lo general Xampp instala los binarios de mysql en

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin
```

Así que un ejemplo con esa ruta sería :

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -h localhost -u root -pDotado256 sixstar_almacen > "AlmacenBeta_19082018.sql"
```

el archivo sql te lo va a grabar donde se ejecute el batch (si es el escritorio lo va a dejar ahi) asi que también le podes poner la ruta completa al archivo onda: `"C:\AlmacenBeta_19082018.sql"`.

- En varias versiones de windows (tendrías que probar tipeando un `SET` en una linea de comandos `CMD` a ver si sale) podes poner `"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\AlmacenBeta_19082018.sql"` para que lo grabe en la carpeta documentos de tu usuario (`Documents` puede ser `Mis Documentos` en versiones español pero creo que hay un symlink que lo toma igual)

Comment: me indica que "mysqldum" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo eso es lo que no entiendo (No debo llamar el mysqldum.exe por medio de un Call? Ejemplo: C\:Xampp\mysql\mysqldum.exe)

Comment: efectivamente si no le tenes en el path par que lo tome hay que darle la ruta completa

Comment: ¿como seria eso? encontre este archivo "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe"